# How to handle the back button on iOS when using a React Navigation Drawer?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am wondering what are common practices of the community, if possible with code, for the following situation:

I have an app that uses the React Navigation Drawer, consequently I always have the hamburger symbol (3 bars) to open the drawer on the top left-hand corner of the navigation bar. In Android everything is fine (thanks to the hardware back button), however, in iOS the hamburger symbol replaces the back button. What solutions are there to cope with this?

Possible ideas that I have are: 
-replacing the hamburger symbol with the back button in nested screens
-leaving the hamburger symbol but disabling the swipe-from-left gesture for the drawer, such that the swipe-from-left gesture goes back
-adding an additional back button next to the hamburger (might look awkward)

I appreciate good propositions and solutions.

Comment: Sorry, i've misunderstood the question, but what i think is there is no need to provide a back button since you can always navigate through the drawer. The drawer always resides on the parent component stack.

Comment: Not exactly, because if you navigate to a StackNavigator which has various screens you can only go back to the initialRoute of this StackNavigator, but I would like to simply go back

Comment: Can you add your navigation structure, it is hard to debug without it.

Comment: Sure:

  StackNavigator(
    {
      LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
      Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
    },
  )

Then the drawer:

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    BusinessScreen: {
      screen: BusinessStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: negociosNavOptions
    },
}

The businessStackNavigator:
 const BusinessStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: NegociosScreen
    },
    Contratos: {
      screen: ContratosScreen
    },
     Entregas: {
      screen: EntregasScreen
     },
}
From "EntregasScreen" I want to go "back"

Comment: copy this comment in a texteditor and format it, otherwise it is dififcult to follow.

Comment: The possible solution if you want to disable the drawer on opening the nested screens is , add your screen as a [modal](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal.html), which would be the full screen, and provide back button to its header.

Comment: Sounds like an idea, I’ll try it as soon as possible

Comment: I've just wanted to answer the same question. Apple phones are indeed strange, they has no hardware back button. How to solve the problem, what is final solution?

Answer (score 2):

**You can disable iOS slide gesture by adding this piece of code to your class**

```
static navigationOptions = {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In a custom button component:

```
<Button title="Back" onClick={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} />
```

And then whichever screen you put it on make sure you pass the navigation prop to you component, like so:

```
<MyCustomButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```